# From where to download Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: release-management

When I am going to download ubuntu desktop on http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/, I can not see ubuntu 14.04, there is only 12.04 and 13.10. From where can I download the final ubuntu14.04 lts desktop edition?NOT any beta edition.

Comment: Please wait for the release announcement - it will be available from the download location as specified in your question.

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 is not officially released yet, but is expected later today. Check back in a few hours and keep an eye on social media as they will probably post it there when it's released.

Comment: wait for few hours , 14 hours may  be ..

Comment: here is the link http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/  enjoy!

Comment: They have not yet updated the main page, but inside links are updated. so you can download from there. 
releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/
Download i386 for 32 bit and amd64 for 64 bit Desktop editions.

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Truaty Tahr, has officially been released, you can download the desktop edition from http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Comment: At what time exactly was it released?